# Knockout.jsでko.observable配下の辞書の変更を検知する方法

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

knockout.jsで以下の様なコードのchild配下の変更を検知できずに困っています。

どのようにすれば実装できるかご教示願います。

```
var SomeVMM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.some = ko.observable();

    self.fire = function(dict){
        self.some([{"title": hoge, "child":dict}]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

前提として変更を受け取るためには`{"title": hoge, "child":dict}`ではなく、`child:ko.observable()`などと設定してやる必要があります。

またタイトルに辞書とありますが、これはkey-value型のコレクションという意味でしょうか？
knockout.jsではそのようなコレクションはサポートされていなかったと記憶していますので、

```
this.child = ko.observableArray();
this.child.push({key:'aaa', value:'bbb'});
```

のように配列で表現することになるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました